# How do I shuffle a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Quick question, I'm trying to display random questions in a simple quiz program using a list of dictionaries. I found a way to do this, but it was fairly drawn out and buggy so I decided it would be much easier to iterate through the questions instead after shuffling them once at the start.

I stumbled across `random.shuffle()` which seems to be just what I want, however, I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
import random

quizBank = {
    1:    ["What is 1+1?\nA) 2\nB) 11\nC) 1\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'A'],
    2:    ["What is 2+2?\nA) 2\nB) 4\nC) 1\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'B'],
    3:    ["What is 3+3?\nA) 2\nB) 11\nC) 6\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'C'],
    4:    ["What is 4+4?\nA) 2\nB) 11\nC) 1\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'D'],
    5:    ["What is 5+5?\nA) 2\nB) 11\nC) 10\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'C'],
    6:    ["What is 6+6?\nA) 2\nB) 12\nC) 1\nD) None of the above.\n\n",'B'],
    }

random.shuffle(quizBank)
print(quizBank)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    random.shuffle(quizBank)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 291, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
KeyError: 0
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and can give me a point in the right direction?

Comment: You have some answers, but a question you should ask yourself is why you're storing the questions this way.  Why put them in a dictionary instead of just using a list of lists?

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unordered, so "shuffling" doesn't make sense; there's no order to change. You can make an ordered structure containing keys and shuffle that.

Comment: Also, your title is wrong, because there is no 'list of dictionaries' here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomly shuffling a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895028/randomly-shuffling-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer I already gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370301/is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-3rd-value-in-python-dictionaries/28370697#28370697) is good. You could also shuffle the values:

```
values = quizBank.values()
random.shuffle(values)
```

One of the reasons that I suggested not using a dict is that once you shuffle, the indexes you setup are shuffled too.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. As for your other solution, I really like it, but as embarrassing as it is to say, I don't really understand it well. Would you be able to edit your previous post with some comments so someone less experienced could understand?

Comment: Added comments to the other answer... hope I didn't make it more confusing!

Answer (score 2):

### My original answer was shuffling keys, not the value mapping

`random.shuffle` is not compatible with a dictionary.  Try shuffling the keys only, then re-indexing the dictionary.

```
newvals = quizBank.values()
random.shuffle(newvals)
randBank = dict((idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate(newvals))
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example for in-place operation

Comment: Even if the re-index operation worked, that's luck rather than guarantee that it'll be true for any given implementation of Python; Python dictionaries don't promise to maintain the order with which items were added.

Comment: To say it's incompatible might be overstating it.  Because Python is not strongly typed, you can substitute a dictionary IFF the keys are the same as the indices that you would find in a list of the same size.  Now, it's not a good idea, because dictionaries aren't meant to be ordered collections, and all you actually do is reassign different values to the keys, so it would be much better to have them as a list of lists (or list of tuples, since each question-answer combination is likely fine being immutable).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a list of dictionaries - you have a dictionary of lists.  Python is trying to use the standard methods to retrieve items in the list by using the bracket notation to get the item corresponding to the first index (0), but it fails because that's not a key in your dictionary.

As an interesting side note, if you make your keys all integers ranging from 0 to length-1, it won't crash!

Comment: To whoever downvoted - I said it won't crash, not that it's a good idea!